# Error in Out Memory FLEX 3

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

friends

It is an urgent problem'm in my flex command when compiling an application in Flex3 gives the error image attached.

ERROR:
An out of memory error has occurred. Consult the "Running Eclipse" section of the read me file for information on preventing this kind of error in the future.

Comment: You forgot to attach the image

Answer (score 2):

By your description it seems you're having an out of memory error. If so, you have to increase the memory given to the java process.

To do this edit eclipse.ini file inside the eclipse folder and add the parameter `-Xmx` with a value, example `-Xmx1024m` which would allow Java to use up to 1Gb of memory.

You can also add this parameter to your JAVA_OPTS

Comment: In my case this folder is located in C :/ Program Files / Adobe / Flex Builder 3/FlexBuilder.ini

and this file contains the following data:

-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX: MaxPermSize = 256m
-XX: PermSize = 64m
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack = true

Which one do I change?

Comment: Change the -Xmx512m (512Mb max) to -Xmx1024m (1Gb max)

Comment: I assign as guided me and it seems that solved my problem. I am very grateful for the help.

The computer company here has 12Gb of DDR3 I wonder if I can add to this parameter more than 1024 if I can add for example 2048 or more?

I would like to apply more memory so I do not have future problems with this type of error

Comment: Glad I could help! Well if you're running a 32Bit JVM you can only address up to 4Gb of maximum heap size (the -Xmx parameter) in a 64bit JVM  (theoretically) you're limited by your physical RAM. __BUT__ you have to keep in mind that larger heap space, means more time wasted in GC which can result in larger waiting times. My suggestion is for you to currently address the 2048m if you can, later on if needed go up to 4096m. Also I've helped you with your problem I suggest you to accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I am very pleased to know that there is so skilled professionals so willing to help other programmers.

Again thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer in order to avoid an answered question being listed as unanswered. How to accept an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235